# What should I use to open a url instead of urlopen in urllib3

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I wanted to write a piece of code like the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.thefamouspeople.com/singers.php'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

But I found that I have to install `urllib3` package now.

Moreover, I couldn't find any tutorial or example to understand how to rewrite the above code, for example, `urllib3` does not have `urlopen`.

Any explanation or example, please?!

P/S: I'm using python 3.4.

Comment: why do you have to install urllib3 when the example works?

Comment: Because it doesn't work for me, no urllib2 found.

Comment: @niloofar Python 3.4 has urllib2 named as urllib. `from urllib import urlopen` should work for this case.

Comment: Don't use urllib3. Do this: `import urllib.request` `urllib.request.urlopen('https://...')`

Answer (score 62):

urllib3 is a different library from urllib and urllib2. It has lots of additional features to the urllibs in the standard library, if you need them, things like re-using connections. The documentation is here: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/

If you'd like to use urllib3, you'll need to `pip install urllib3`. A basic example looks like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = 'http://www.thefamouspeople.com/singers.php'
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)
```

Comment: `response.read()` does not work at least in Python 2.7. As per the documentation https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html it should be
`html = response.data`.

Comment: This example give me a an exception error (urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError) python3

Answer (score 40):

*You do not have to install `urllib3`*. You can choose any HTTP-request-making library that fits your needs and feed the response to `BeautifulSoup`. The choice is though usually [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) because of the rich feature set and convenient API. You can install `requests` by entering `pip install requests` in the command line. Here is a basic example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "url"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
```

Comment: FWIW, you still need to _install_ requests if you want to use requests. Neither of them come native with Python.

Comment: Requests depends on urllib3.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman I tried requests without urlib3 and it works, why it depends on urllib3?

Answer (score 13):

The new **urllib3** library has a nice documentation [here](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
In order to get your desired result you shuld follow that:

```
Import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.thefamouspeople.com/singers.php'

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

The "decode utf-8" part is optional. It worked without it when i tried, but i posted the option anyway.
Source: [User Guide](http://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html)

Comment: is requests simply using urllib3 behind the scenes

Comment: @PirateApp It is.

Answer (score 0):

With [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho) you could pipeline the page straight into a parse-able soup object:

```py
from gazpacho import Soup
url = "http://www.thefamouspeople.com/singers.php"
soup = Soup.get(url)
```

And run finds on top of it:

```py
soup.find("div")
```

Answer (score 0):

In urlip3 there's no `.urlopen`, instead try this:

```py
import requests
html = requests.get(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use urllib.reuqest, not urllib3.

```
import urllib.request   # not urllib - important!
urllib.request.urlopen('https://...')
```